# VMware Fault Tolerance possible Tests

Tags: vmware, fault-tolerance

I have been thinking about how I can test my Fault Tolerance machines.
But I can't seem to come with a proper test.

How can I possibly calculate the time it took for VMware to switch from the primary virtual machine to the secondary one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ping the VM and kill the host where the primary runs, how many pings do you loose? This should give you a feeling for the time it takes vSphere to switch from the primary virtual machine to the secondary.